# Highcharts Credits itemStyle not working

Tags: highcharts

I need the credits line to be underlined. If I take the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hofo/SrQaX/6/) of the credits and add the itemStyle from the API it doesn't work. Even with just textDecoration. What's the trick here? textDecoration seems to work with legend.

```
    credits: {
        text: 'Example.com',
        href: 'http://www.example.com',
        itemStyle: {
            textDecoration: 'underline',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            color: '#909090',
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `style`, not `itemStyle`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/SrQaX/7/ docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits.style